# Android Language Change

Tags: languages, user-interface

I have a LG Android.  How do I change language settings on the phone itself?  Sometime today, the language on the phone displays changed from English.  I'd like to return to English.  I suspect it'd be in settings, but where?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can change it in Settings/Language & keyboard.

To do this, hold down the menu button, and choose Settings.  In your Settings list, you will see Language & keyboard.  The first option in the Language & keyboard section is Language.